# .appendChild(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

So I seem to keep getting this error $(...).appendChild is not a function! I would like to quite simply create an element, give it some text and append it back to the ul. I have checked all references on jquery and have come back empty handed.

```js
const ul = $('#element');

const $li = $('<li>');
$li.innerText = 'hello';
$('#blog-prev-title').appendChild($li);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="element">
</ul>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Because it is NOT a function of jQuery aka, $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use append() instead of appendChild(), appendChild is a DOM method whereas append is a JQuery method

Answer (score 0):

You want to use .append(). `$('#blog-prev-title').append($li);`

Answer (score 0):

Either you use jQuery or pure javascript. You are selecting the element with jQuery and then trying to append with javascript

so it's either pure js:

document.getElementById("blog-prev-title").appendChild($li);

or jQuery:

$('#blog-prev-title').append($li);